# Corrupted boot sequence

Tags: macos, startup

I recently incurred a corruption of the boot sequence when I used my mac to install ubuntu onto an USB drive. I had one USB with a live bistro, and I had one which was the target drive. I successfully installed ubuntu onto the target drive, however it seems that ubuntu had written a file to my actual mac hard drive, which corrupted the boot sequence. It placed grub at startup. Now to boot from my mac drive I have to hold the option key to present my mac hard drive. I have booted from recovery mode, command + r, and reinstalled the OS but it has not fixed the issue. I expected the reinstall to fix the issue. Can anyone give suggestions on how to to fix this issue ?
I am using v10.15.5 OSX on a MacBook air 2012.

Comment: Did you try selecting the macOS system in the Startup Disk pane in System Preferences?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Gordon. I resolved the issue by repeating the macOS install from recovery. In fact I repeated twice. The second time I installed macOS from recovery, it didn’t allow me to do the install because there was not enough space. So I had to delete before trying again. The third time I installed macOS it seemed to resolve the issue. I don’t have a clear picture of what happened as the 1st time seemed to complete as it took several hours and only completed at the end of its process.